# Add and change border type, color and thickness to a path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, path, stroke, maps

I want to create a map, with lines that have borders like roads or railway lines, either solid or dotted borders like normal OS maps.

I have tried to draw lines with the pen tool (and this would be my preferred tool) - but cannot see how to add a border to them or to change the thickness and body colour.

Mostly I use Photoshop for pure image work.

Answer (score 1):

This type of work is better done in a vector program such as Illustrator or Inkscape.

In Photoshop, after choosing the Pen Tool, at the **Top Options Panel** > **Shape** must be checked

[image: top options]

Once the path is done, from this same panel you can choose the stroke options:

[image: path]

If the path is a shape, the modification options are at the Top Panel or at the **Properties Panel**

[image]

——————————————————————————————————————————

Photoshop old versions, the most immediate option is to stroke the path from the **Paths Panel**:

- Once you have the path/s and working in an empty layer, select a path with the **Path Selection Tool**
- Choose the **Brush Tool** or **Pencil Tool**
- Choose the tool options: thickness, hardness and spacing for the dotted lines
- Choose a front color
- Click on the **Stroke Path Icon** at the bottom of the **Paths Panel**

[image: paths panel]

Comment: Ooops Thanks Danielillo - but I don't have those options in CS3 for some reason??  I know Illustrator would be good, but there is also a lot of work to do in PS, so rather than swap programs all the time, I wanted to see if I could do it all in PS

Comment: @ColinWoolf I think that better than changing programs, update the one you have, you are 22 versions below the current one :-/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop_version_history

Comment: :-)) For the times I need to tuse it it is hardly worth it.  I will investigate Inkscape.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @ColinWoolf I update the answer with a solution for old PS versions.

Comment: @ColinWoolf and how exactly will switching to inkscape help your switching problem. It make it more acute.